# Using groupby() and cut() in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe and for each group value I want to label values. If value is less that group mean then label is 1 and if group value is more than group mean then label is 2.

input data frame is

```
         groups  num1 
0        a     2    
1        a     5     
2        a     Nan    
3        b    10    
4        b     4     
5        b     0     
6        b     7     
7        c     2    
8        c     4     
9        c     1
```

Here mean values for group a, b ,c are  3.5, 5.25 and  2.33 respectively and output data frame is .

```
       groups  out
0        a     1    
1        a     2     
2        a     Nan    
3        b     2    
4        b     1     
5        b     1     
6        b     2     
7        c     1    
8        c     2     
9        c     1
```

I want to use  `panads.cut` and may be `pandas.groupby` and `pandas.apply` also.

and also how can I skip Null values here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut` is not really pertinent here. Use `groupby.transform('mean')` and `numpy.where`:

```
df['out'] = np.where(df['num1'].lt(df.groupby('groups')['num1']
                                     .transform('mean')),
                     1, 2)
```

Output (as new column "out" for clarity):

```
  groups  num1  out
0      a     2    1
1      a     5    2
2      a     7    2
3      b    10    2
4      b     4    1
5      b     0    1
6      b     7    2
7      c     2    1
8      c     4    2
9      c     1    1
```

###### I really want `cut`

OK, but it's not really nice and performant:

```
(df.groupby('groups')['num1']
   .transform(lambda g: pd.cut(g, [-np.inf, g.mean(), np.inf], labels=[1, 2]))
)
```

Comment: `cut` is preferred because I need to handle few more conditions for labels. Thanks it works

Comment: I have edited question , I want to skip null values in binning column .